# Is there a way to always 'Continue to the next Act' in Sonic 4?

Tags: sonic-the-hedgehog-4-episode-1

I find it really annoying that (upon completing a Zone/Act) I am taken back to the level select screen by default. I feel that this breaks the continuity of the game, especially seeing as I can then go back and re-play a level in order to improve my score/have another crack at that Chaos Emerald Challenge.

Obviously I know about the *Play the Next Act* button, seen below. The problem is that if I don't remember to hit that button, the game quits out to the level select screen. What I would like to do is automate this, so the only way out is to quit via the pause menu. That way I wont have to remember to hit this button every time.

I'm playing on PC, and I've been through the game's configuration settings, but they only really provide some simple graphics/resolution stuff and keybind settings.

Is there a config file that I can edit, or failing that a game mod or tool that exposes this functionality?

[image: screencap of the 'Play the next Act' button on the score screen]

Comment: I would like to know your opinion on quick time events.

Comment: @SteveKB - they make the game more about time, and less about exploring, solving puzzles/obstacles and killing badniks. I never liked the time aspect of the games, so I didn't enjoy the change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no config file that you can modify to allow this functionality. And there are **no** mods that will allow you to change this aspect of the game. The best way to go to the next act is by pressing the next act button.

Comment: Well, I'll accept for now, although I hold out hope :/